# Can't get my rspec test to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a test I'm trying to pass but I can't get it to pass, I am new to this.

Here's a link to my git repository https://github.com/FrankWiebe/nameofapp

The failure message comes up like so:

```
1) UsersController GET #show No user is logged in redirects to login
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:24:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

> This is the code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe UsersController, :type => :controller do

    before do
        @user = User.create(email: "doe@example.com", password: "1234567890")
    end

    describe "GET #show" do
        context "User is logged in" do
            before do
                sign_in @user
            end
            it "loads correct user details" do
                get :show, id: @user.id
                expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
                expect(assigns(:user)).to eq @user
            end
        end

        context "No user is logged in" do
           it "redirects to login" do
             get :show, id: @user.id
             expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
           end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: whats the failure message?

Comment: added failure message.

Comment: where is `load_and_authorize_resource` in your UsersController defined?

Comment: it's on the third line in the users_controller.rb or do you mean in the users_controller_spec.rb file? because it's not in there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps @user is carried on as being logged in from one test to the next, so the 2nd show succeeds. Try to sign off the user whithin the first test.

As this is not the case, check your config/routes.rb.
Resources requiring login should be wrapped within a do...end

```
authenticate(:user) do
  resources :user
  ...other stuff
end
```

Comment: tried to add authenticate(:user) do and still the same error, unless this is wrong `authenticate(:user) do
    resources :users
  end`